# Wordpress Custom Plugin Conflicting with other Menu Items

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

website: bartenders.ca

When the plugin is turned on I loose access to

1. Wordpress mobile hamburger dashboard menu (it works on desktop but not mobile)
2. Yoast SEO plugin looses the ability to change information
3. Visual Composer doesn't register to be used at all.
4. Hind theme Theme Options displays the menu but no information inside.

It looks like the author when using javascript/jquery they called it like this...

```
   1.)  jQuery(document).ready(function () {}
   2.)  $("#add-new").on("click", function () {
        $("form#add-course").slideDown();
    });
```

... as I understand this can override or alter other code calling jQuery similarly?

It looks like the css used calls specific class and id elements... but I'm missing something, but initial guess is conflict with jquery but I'm lost.

admin.php file

function my_admin_menu() {

```
add_menu_page('Enroll Form', 'Enroll Form from down under', 'manage_options', 'jbef_enroll-form', 'jbef_view_all', 'dashicons-tickets', 6);

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'How to Use', 'How to Use', 'manage_options', 'jbef_enroll-form', 'jbef_how_to_use');

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'Manage Courses for Montreal', 'Montreal Courses', 'manage_options', 'jbef_montreal-courses', 'jbef_manage_courses_page_m');

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'Manage Schedules for Montreal', 'Montreal Schedules', 'manage_options', 'jbef_montreal-schedules', 'jbef_manage_schedules_page_m');

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'Manage Courses for Quebec', 'Quebec Courses', 'manage_options', 'jbef_quebec-courses', 'jbef_manage_courses_page_q');

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'Manage Schedules for Quebec', 'Quebec Schedules', 'manage_options', 'jbef_quebec-schedules', 'jbef_manage_schedules_page_q');

add_submenu_page('jbef_enroll-form', 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'jbef_settings', 'jbef_settings_page');
```

}

function jbef_admin_scripts() {

```
wp_register_script('jbef_jquery', plugins_url('bartend-enroll-form/js/jquery.min.js'), false, '3.1.1');

wp_enqueue_script('jbef_jquery');

wp_register_style('jbef_admin_style', plugins_url('bartend-enroll-form/style/admin.css'));

wp_enqueue_style('jbef_admin_style');
```

}

Comment: It's an enroll plugin...http://bartenders.ca/enroll-montreal/ , http://bartenders.ca/schedules/, the plugin functions properly but it breaks everything else it seems.

Comment: Hind theme ... https://themeforest.net/item/hind-multiconcept-portfolio-wordpress-theme/12643880 link to theme used that

Comment: Do you see any error in the debugger console? Sounds like JavaScript error.

Comment: I'll check the deubgger console, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the $ with the word jQuery. Sometimes wordpress does not like the $ variable. So it would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#add-new").on("click", function () {
        jQuery("form#add-course").slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again... I went through and made sure to replace all the $ calls with jQuery that helped... also I blocked out some code and that seemed to help as well... I think it might have been a mix of the two solutions, so thank you! =)                                      function jbef_admin_scripts() {
    //wp_register_script('jbef_jquery', plugins_url('bartend-enroll-form/js/jquery.min.js'), false, '3.1.1');
    //wp_enqueue_script('jbef_jquery');
    wp_register_style('jbef_admin_style', plugins_url('bartend-enroll-form/style/admin.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('jbef_admin_style');
}

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out :)